# Apostrophes around words are the wrong way round

Tags: symbols

If I use apostrophes around a word, the first one is the wrong way round. For example,

```
'word'
```

appears as 
’word’

Comment: the input is incorrect: it should be `\`word'`

Comment: You should search and replace ` '` (space-single quote) in your source with space-open quote (the character under ~). And then just search for the single quotes that do not follow spaces.

Comment: Or use `xelatex` and type proper Unicode quotes like this: `‘word’`.  (Assuming you have a keyboard and an editor capable of dealing with them.)

Comment: Or use the csquotes package and `\enquote*{word}`.

Comment: Please remove the greengrocers' apostrophe in `apostrophe's`.

Answer (score 6):

Summarising the comments, your input is incorrect it should be

```
`word'
```

or, with an up-to-date TeX distribution,

```
‘word’
```

using the Unicode quotes U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK and U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK.

However, it is often easier to use the [`textcmds` package](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/textcmds.pdf) and write

```
\q{word}
```

or the more sophisticated [`csquotes` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes?lang=en), and so write

```
\enquote{word}
```

or

```
\enquote*{word}
```

---

What about math? Well, with `unicode-math` (with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX) an input such as

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

$\mathrm{‘E’}$

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

With pdflatex it's a bit more complicated:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\vmathrm}[1]{
  \mathrm{%
    \def\textquoteleft{`}%
    \def\textquoteright{'}%
    \mathcode`\'=`\' #1%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\vmathrm{`E'}$

$\vmathrm{‘E’}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, using the `word' style does not work when we use maths formulas in a Math syntax based on TeX: the leading quote is correctly rounded, but the last quote looks like a prime and does not pair correctly, so we actually get this in TeX Maths:

```
DL[6]=\mathrm{`E'}, DL[6]=\mathrm{'E'}
```

gives (both styles are NOT correct):

> *DL*[6] = ‘E′, *DL*[6] = ′E′

What I really want is:

> *DL*[6] = ‘E’

i.e. without any mathematical "prime" symbol substituted only for one of the quotes. Both quotation marks should have the same style and should be correctly oriented. (this is the same question as the question starting this thread, except that it was intended for rendering normal text documents, so he got the two ASCII quotes rendered by the same curly last quote, instead of the same prime symbol that we get in the context of Maths TeX formulas).

And I found no way in math packages to get the correct second last quote
The same also applies to double-quotes which can be rendered both in curly style, but not correctly oriented, or if we try using angle quotation marks (guillemets) which are not supported (using "<<" and ">>" generates large mathematical signs, centered vertically like operators, instead of small kerned chevrons on the text baseline)

So how can we safely insert text values in some Maths formulas computing textual values (this is a problem for any maths about formal languages when we really need textual quotation marks).

The best I could do with Math TeX packages was to use the the same symbol for both the leading and ending quotation marks (i.e. using the ASCII tick for both quotation marks, both rendered as prime symbols).

---

Note also that quotation marks are language-dependant, and the ASCII apostrophe (vertical tick) is not suitable at all in French as a true apostrophe, if it is also used as quotation mark (which is inappropriate in French which uses chevrons instead): the French apostrophe is curly is the same glyph like the English last quote, so the last quotation mark in French cannot be ANY single quote.

Various languages also have two distinct apostrophe-like letters, so they also need other quotation marks (small chevrons like French, or rectangular brackets like Chinese or Japanese). Here again they have problem rendering mathematical formulas computing textual values or where there's a need to add some text at end of each case in a conditional formula.

Do we have somewhere a correct package or solution for maths formulas (including on wikis) so we can properly use the correct punctuations? Using an UTF-8 encoded character still does not work in most mathTeX renderer, and as well the "\char{}" syntax does not work or does not accept any non-ASCII codepoint!

I just hope that some day (when?) all TeX processors (xelatex?) will accept non-ASCII input, so that we can use directly UTF-8 encoded characters without even having to use the overly-complex TeX syntax or unstable packages. But if we have to use a TeX syntax in 7-bit ASCII only, the "\char{codepoint}" should accept any valid Unicode code point in decimal, or "\U{hexcodepoint}" should do the same with hexadecimal: then "\U{2018}" or "\char{8216}" will both render the leading curly quote everywhere in a math formula (including inside "\mathrm{...}", but also in variable names (TeX formulas should infer the italic or bold styles as appropriate); we should no longer have to use the overcomplex syntax for letters with diacritics if we could directly use the UTF-8 encoding for combining sequences or sequences of "char{}" or "\U{}".

But TeX design is so old-aged that it is now outdated, we should forget ASCII; when will TeX designers adopt the Unicode standard? It would facilitate the life for everybody, making formulas much simpler to edit in frequent cases, without forcing users to use only basic English text and basic English punctuation rules.

(Allmost all fonts used by TeX renderers support, and in fact require, now an Unicode mapping of their glyphs; fonts with legacy mappings are no longer supported as they don't have the correct coverage, except for specific maths symbols treated specially with constraints on glyph size, padding and positioning so they can lineup correctly, like variable horizontal bars, or bars over radicals, or resizable delimiters for arrays/matrixes).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107570/discussion-on-answer-by-verdy-p-apostrophes-around-words-are-the-wrong-way-round).